# When I try to implement appium-flutter-driver in java, the appium-flutter-finder dependency does not work someone knows how to fix it?

Tags: java, flutter, appium

I'm trying to implement appium-flutter-driver in an automation project, I'm trying to make a POC with the example that is in the repo https://github.com/truongsinh/appium-flutter-driver

When I made an `mvn clean install` the appium-flutter-finder dependency does not work with the next error message

```
Could not transfer artifact pro.truongsinh:appium-flutter-finder:pom:0.0.4 from/to saucelabs-repository (https://repository-saucelabs.forge.cloudbees.com/release): repository-saucelabs.forge.cloudbees.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Does someone know which is my error? or if someone has some example with java I appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think pro.truongsinh:appium-flutter-finder is not in the Maven Repository because of that we can not use this one.

I have created an automation project to test a flutter app using the Appium Flutter Driver.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0IHGIFlIFQ&ab_channel=GihanWijesekara

You can download the project which I have created using https://github.com/gihanchandana46/AppiumFlutterDriver

Comment: I am facing the same error.Anything to do with downloading of. jar  files for FlutterFinder and FlutterElement.If I find flutter finder in ur git repository  shall I use the same in my pom.xml